# What is the purpose of a farm file in CQ5?

Tags: content-management-system, aem

Can any one explain to me what a farm file is in CQ5 and what its purpose is?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of the `/farms` node in the dispatcher configuration file.  As [this doc](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/deploying/installingandconfiguringadditionaltoolsmodules.html) (somewhat outdated, as it applies to 5.3) indicates, your config entries for this node can be coded in a separate, included file.  Each entry in `/farms` describes a separate server that can provide content; requests are routed to the servers by the dispatcher.